# How to replace a part of the string using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 100 email address in my `mysql` table and its look like `abc@xy.com, fdgf@xy.com, ghfe@xy.com, erekke@xyz.com,tty@xyz.com, ere@xy.com, ect...`. I need to change all `@xy.com` to `@xyz.com` using `mysql` query.

Please help me for query

Thanks in advance!

Comment: replace(email, '@xy.com', '@xyz.com')?

Comment: You'll need to show some effort yourself. Just as a hint, you will be looking at using `LIKE` in the `WHERE` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
update myTable
set email = replace(email, '@xy.com', '@xyz.com')
where email like '%@xy.com'
```