# Update two table fields value using MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two MySQL table with contain values like

table1

```
id  email_id  
===========
1   abc@xyz.com     
2   bbc@xy.com
3   gty@xyz.com
4   iut@xyz.com
5   tyk@xy.com
```

table2

```
id  name email_id  
===========
1   abc  abc@xy.com     
2   bbc  bbc@xy.com
3   gty  gty@xy.com
4   iut  iut@xy.com
5   tyk  tyk@xy.com
6   tyr  tyr@xy.com
7   iut  iut@xy.com
```

Result

table2

```
id  name email_id  
===========
1   abc  abc@xyz.com     
2   bbc  bbc@xy.com
3   gty  gty@xyz.com
4   iut  iut@xyz.com
5   tyk  tyk@xy.com
6   tyr  tyr@xy.com
7   iut  iut@xyz.com
```

You can see in my first table is a combination of @xy.com and @xyz.com. So i need to change all @xy.com to @xyz.com in table2 whether if table1 is same  @xyz.com.

Example:  case1- in table1 abc@xyz.com is available and its @xyz format, so in table2 i needs to change it as abc@xyz.com

case2- in table1 bbc@xy.com is available and its in @xy format, So in table2 i need not change bbc@xyz.com. i can leave it as it is.
i think you understood my issue and please give me a mysql query for solve it.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why both MySQL and MS SQL Server tags? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: @pk20 i used this query "update table2 a, table1 b set a.email_id = replace(a.email_id, '@xy.com', '@xyz.com') where a.email_id like '%@xy.com' and (a.email_id = b.emailid)". But the abbove query is not correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a part of the string using mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606084/how-to-replace-a-part-of-the-string-using-mysql)

Comment: @jarlh It's not a duplicate of that. its more differ from that query.

Comment: Sorry, I've already noticed.

Answer (score 0):

You can join together `table1` and `table2` and then compare the length of the email addresses for each `id`.  Since you want to conditionally replace the `@xy` format with the `@xyz` format, you can simply choose the *longer* email address to retain in the query.

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.name,
    CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(t2.email_id) > CHAR_LENGTH(COALESCE(t1.email_id, ''))
        THEN t2.email_id ELSE t1.email_id END AS email_id
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

i had written in sql server

```
create table #stack_table1(id int identity(1,1),
email_id varchar(1000))

create table #stack_table2(id int ,
name varchar(50),
email_id varchar(1000)
)



insert into #stack_table1(email_id)
(select ('abc@xyz.com')
union
select ('bbc@xy.com')
union
select ('gty@xyz.com')
union
select ('iut@xyz.com')
union
select ('tyk@xy.com')
)


insert into #stack_table2(id,name,email_id)
(
select 1,'abc','abc@xy.com'
union
select 2,'bbc','bbc@xy.com'
union
select 3,'gty','gty@xy.com'
union
select 4,'iut','iut@xy.com'
union
select 5,'tyk','tyk@xy.com'
union
select 6,'tyr','tyr@xy.com'
union
select 7,'iut','iut@xy.com'
)

select * from #stack_table1
select * from #stack_table2
```

tables were created

update statement will be as follows

```
UPDATE st2
SET st2.email_id = st1.email_id
FROM #stack_table1 st1
JOIN #stack_table2 st2 ON st2.NAME = substring(st1.email_id, 1, CHARINDEX('@', st1.email_id, 1) - 1)
```

if only select query needed please use this

```
SELECT st2.id
    ,st2.NAME
    ,coalesce(st1.email_id, st2.email_id)
FROM #stack_table1 st1
RIGHT JOIN #stack_table2 st2 ON st2.NAME = substring(st1.email_id, 1, CHARINDEX('@', st1.email_id, 1) - 1)
```